Will deck stain darken with a longer drying time?
I had my deck professionally cleaned and stained with a dark oil this weekend. The guy did 2 coats on half of the deck then had to stop due to rain. He came back a few hours later when it was dry and sunny, and did the 2nd half. This morning, the first half looks a good shade lighter than the 2nd half.
Should I give it a few days to properly dry out, or does it sound like I need to ask the guy to come back and put another coat on the first half? Thanks

If he stopped in the middle of a board, then he will need to try and blend it or recoat the entire deck. If he stopped at the end of the boards (where 2 boards come together) then he needs to recoat the lighter side.
